# ngmoco cache money rails 3 ruby 1.9.2 uninitialized constant CacheMoney

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've trying to setup cache money for rails 3.0, but i am getting the following error[image]

Gemfile

[image]

environment.rb

[image]

config/initializers/cache_money.rb
[image]

Comment: I am also experiencing this error as well. I just upgraded my rails app from v2 to v3 and switched to ngmoco's fork of Cache Money from nkallen's fork, which doesn't seem to have Rails 3 support.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately cache-money doesn't currently work with Rails3. There's an experimental branch here, but AFAIK it isn't quite ready yet:

https://github.com/ngmoco/cache-money/tree/rails3

Comment: The title of the question indicates he's using that fork on rails 3 already and is experiencing this error.

Comment: Shaun -- he's using the ngmoco *fork* but not using the (incomplete) rails3 *branch*.